# IIS rewrite produces different outcome with $_GET request than Apache

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I have recently made the switch on my localhost to IIS but I'm running into a few things that I don't understand.

I have a Rewrite rule that is setup like.

```
<rule name="Pages" stopProcessing="true">  
     <match url="^page/(.*)/$" ignoreCase="true" />  
     <action type="Rewrite" redirectType="Permanent" url="/resources/pages/getPage.php?page={R:0}" />  
</rule>
```

This is working as it should where

```
localhost/page/login/
```

will take you to

```
localhost/resources/pages/getPage.php?page=login
```

where getPage.php will server up the needed page for the user.

When I run

```
$_GET['page]
```

on the getPage.php script it returns

```
page/login/
```

This is the same as $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] sans the leading "/" I would expect it to result only in "login". While running Apache this is how it worked. So what is wrong or different about how IIS handles this sort of rewrite?

Comment: I think that the first match `R:0` is the full match (the complete string) while `R:1` is the first catch group (which is `login`). Try it with `?page={R:1}` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, this does work but still is a different result than I received in Apache. For instance if I send the URL localhost/page/login/test/10, {R:1} returns login/test/10 as you have pointed out. But in Apache it would have just been login. It separates them into pairs I guess.

Comment: That's because you have `(.*)/$` which is _"catch everything up to the last slash"_. That would have been the same with mod_rewrite in Apache.

Comment: What would the regex be to catch them as pairs?

Comment: I really do need to get better at regex. 
Thanks I will see if I can get that to work.

Comment: This ^page/([\w_]+) worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently fetching `R:0` which is the full match of the complete string. To fetch the first regex group `(.*)`, you need to use `R:1`

So change to:

```
url="/resources/pages/getPage.php?page={R:1}"
```

However, your match group `(.*)` will match *everything* up to the last slash. If you want to match more groups, you need to be more specific, like:

```
^page/([\w_]+)/$
```

Here, `\w` will match alphanumeric characters and dashes. The `_` matches underscores.

To have more segments:

```
^page/([\w_]+)/([\w_]+)/$
```

...and so on. If you want to only match numbers, you can add a `([\d]+)`.

And remember that you need to use `R:1`, `R:2` etc, depending on which group you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Example IIS web.config rule remove index.php from yoursite/index.php/controller/page/

```
      <rule name="CodeIgniter Url Rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />          
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation? And please don't write your text all in bold.

Comment: Explanation would be great as I'm not sure how that applies to what I'm asking.

Comment: @PaulNeale The only thing you need to care about in this answer is `{R:1}`. Nothing else isn't relevant to your question since this is a "catch-all" route.

Comment: yeah sorry, too much.